# Trying to put a dynamic SQL subquery result into SQL-Server 2008 temp table without pre define the temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, dynamic-sql, temp-tables

I´m trying to get my result into a temp table but can´t get it to work.

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)
SET @query = N'SELECT * INTO ##TmpTbl FROM (SELECT * FROM Tbl1)'
EXEC(@query)
```

What am i doing wrong?

> NOTE: I can NOT pre define temp table/table variable because of the actual
>   question being run is a pivot question without pre defined columns in
>   it´s result.

Comment: Did you try giving the sub query an alias?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the alias on the subquery:

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)
SET @query = N'SELECT * 
               INTO ##TmpTbl 
               FROM (SELECT * FROM Tbl1) src'  <--- you need an alias
EXEC(@query)
```